# Exception handling, error messages and i18n

Tags: c#, .net, exception

In my application, while logging exceptions, I need to show user friendly and localized error messages to the clients.

ie: CustomerNotFoundException should display the following to end user.

`Customer-001 
Customer was not found`

I hope it is clear so far. I have services for i18n and error messages.

My error messages microservis provides key value pairs of Language, ErrorId and Error Message:
ie:
`Error: Customer -001; Message: Customer Not found; Language:en-US`

My question is about designing this process:

Should I convert exceptions to error messages that can be displayed to clients in a middleware? if so how do i map exceptions to error messages?

Or Should I inject ErrorService or I18N service in to the exceptions to provide message etc to the client ?

or is there a better way?